# Build using react-native run-android fails when using react-native-chart-android

Tags: react-native

My react native run android fails with following error:

> C:\Users\abhay\React\infp_devices\android\app\src\main\java\com\infp_devices\MainActivity.java:19:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       protected List getPackages() {
>                 ^   symbol:   class List   location: class MainActivity C:\Users\abhay\React\infp_devices\android\app\src\main\java\com\infp_devices\MainActivity.java:19:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       protected List getPackages() {
>                      ^   symbol:   class ReactPackage   location: class MainActivity
>   C:\Users\abhay\React\infp_devices\android\app\src\main\java\com\infp_devices\MainActivity.java:18:
>   error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>       @Override
>       ^ C:\Users\abhay\React\infp_devices\android\app\src\main\java\com\infp_devices\MainActivity.java:21:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>           new MainReactPackage(),
>               ^   symbol:   class MainReactPackage   location: class MainActivity
>   C:\Users\abhay\React\infp_devices\android\app\src\main\java\com\infp_devices\MainActivity.java:20:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>         return Arrays.asList(
>                        ^   symbol:   class ReactPackage   location: class MainActivity
>   C:\Users\abhay\React\infp_devices\android\app\src\main\java\com\infp_devices\MainActivity.java:20:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>         return Arrays.asList(
>                ^   symbol:   variable Arrays   location: class MainActivity 6 errors :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

I have made following changes :

In android/setting.gradle :

```
include ':react-native-chart-android'
project(':react-native-chart-android').projectDir = new 
File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-chart-
android/android')
```

In android/app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_module
    compile project(':react-native-chart-android') //Changes to the code
}
```

My entire android/app/src/main/java/com/xxxxxxx/MainActivity.java, (XXXXXXX is my app name), looks as follows :

```
package com.xxxxxxx;  // xxxxxxx is my app name

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

import cn.mandata.react_native_mpchart.MPChartPackage;  // <--- import

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "xxxxxxx";   //xxxxxxx is my app name
        }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new MainReactPackage(),
        new MPChartPackage());
}
}
```

My application code looks as follows :

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

import {
  BarChart,
  CombinedChart
} from 'react-native-chart-android';

import { getBarData } from './graphComponent';


const graphDisplay = (props) => {
  // const myData = getBarData();
  return (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <BarChart style={{flex:1}} data={getBarData()} />
   /View>
    );
});

export default graphDisplay;
```

I get a fatal ESLint error on the BarChart tag line as "Unterminated JSX content (Fatal)". However I have not got around to solving it. Not sure if it is relevant for this problem.

Please help

Edited:

My code for the imported getBarData() function is as follows:

```
export function getBarData() {
  const data = {
    xValues: ['1', '2', '3'],
    yValues: [
      {
        data: [4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
        label: 'test1',
        config: {
          color: 'blue'
        }
      },
      {
        data: [4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
        label: 'test2',
        config: {
          color: 'red'
        }
      },
      {
        data: [4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
        label: 'test2',
        config: {
          color: 'yellow'
        }
    }
    ]
  };
  return (data);
}
```